# Violin plots not plotting over xticks in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I am plotting data in seaborn using a violin plot, and the plots are not centering over the xticks. If I strike the "hue" argument, they align, but everything looks bad, and I would like to keep the hues. Any advice?

Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(violin_data, y = 'Height', x = 'Sample', ax= ax, hue= 'scalloped')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('Intermediate Length ($\mu$m)')
plt.legend(title = '')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[snippet of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPKM.png)

[output of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbpAS.png)

Comment: If each of the x-values only exists in one hue category, you can use `sns.violinplot(..., dodge=False)` to avoid that the hue values are spread out.